# Oracle database uses wrong parameter file

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, configuration

When I try to startup my Oracle database I get the following error:

```
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/dbs/initjicdbaex.ora'
```

The `/dbs` directory in my Oracle home contains the `init.ora` file I want to use, but I don't know how to point the database to read that file.

How do I set the correct parameter file path to `init.ora`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not or at least you should not. The right pfile (or spfile) should contain ORACLE_SID in it's name.

Theoretically you  can start the database using:

```
SQL> startup pfile='<path to init.ora>'
```

But I won't recommend it.

Comment: `initjicdbaex.ora` is perfectly valid name for an initialization parameter file. The instance name portion here is `jicdbaex`.

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle database tries to initialize looking for the following files in the order they appear in the following list:

1. `spfileSID.ora`
2. `spfile.ora`
3. `initSID.ora`

Thus `init.ora` is the incorrect name for text initialization parameter file, and you should rename it to `initSID.ora`, where `SID` is the name of your instance (`jicdbaex`).